# Как сохранить новое значение в Plist (словарь)

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть собственно plist он же словарь(NSDictionary)

[image: Swa.Plist]

он реализуется через массив (fruit) (картинки,текст) и т.д. , все показывается все загружается через collectionView и выводится на ViewController.
После реализуется проверка у меня через кнопку и вот необходимо изменить значение Boolean из false на True, ну в принцепе дать ему значение true нет проблем (fruit.correctText = true ) но при перезапуске этой ячейки мы имееи все тоже значение false. 
Вопрос как его заставить записать новое значение Bool?

p.s Два параметра boolean подключены и согласованны как не обязательны (bool?) дабы избежать fatal и ошибок на данном этапе эксперементов. Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после изменения надо это все обратно записать в файл, примерно так

```
let plist = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: "file.plist")
plist?.setObject(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: "EditThis")
plist?.writeToFile("file.plist", atomically: true)
```

objC

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"file.plist"];
[plist setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"EditThis"];
[plist writeToFile:@"file.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Это на Obj C а на Swift ?

Comment: уже оба (добавил в ответ)

Comment: Да спасибо выглядит норм по смыслу, но не могу разобраться по итогу  NSMutableDictionary выводит в консоле nil а тем самым ничего не записывает. [ссылка](http://i057.radikal.ru/1605/94/1ec93e7c77a8.png)  а здесь реализуется сам словарь и подключается [ссылка](http://s018.radikal.ru/i503/1605/2f/f99a7c5b73f6.png) Если можеш помоги разобраться.

Comment: проще весь код посмотреть и скомпилировать, если там ничего секретного нет

Comment: Ну как бы не секретно)) куда скинуть лучше ?

Comment: на github проще всего

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/Fecla/FruitsDiet-master) скайп Fecla1990

Comment: корневая структура в вашем plist - массив. вам и читать ее надо в массив `let resultDictionary = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)`

Comment: Хорошо что же получается:                                                                   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Swa", ofType: "plist")
            let resultDictionary = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
            resultDictionary!.setObject(NSNumber(bool: true), atIndexedSubscript: ?????)
            resultDictionary!.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)      и что за аргумент необходимо вписать? (atIndexedSubscript: ?????)

Comment: у вас есть массив, состоящий из словарей. сначала надо найти нужный словарь, потом изменить в нем значение, записать его обратно в массив на то же место, и сохранить все это дело обратно в plist

Comment: Принцип я понимаю, я ж пишу что находим словарь (path) потом пишу что будем изменять через NSMutableArray в path (динамическое значение) после говорим что выбираем объект такой-то (меняется значение) и в конце концов делаем запись через writeToFile в path и даем ему значение true чтоб выполнил. Меня интересует atIndexedSubscript ? мне нужно через Int показать какой объект я хочу поменять?

Comment: я даже не знаю что это за indexSubscript. это какого класса метод? вам надо из массива словарей найти нужный словарь (черезе enumerate) поменять значение в словаре через setObject:forKey; и сохранить

Comment: Incorrect argument label in call (have '_:forKey:', expected '_:atIndexedSubscript:') xCode пишет если значение forKey оставить и предлогает поменять на этот . А этот класс я как понимаю NSMutableArray вот откуда ноги растут но на офф сайте эпл об этом ни слова, встречается только в Objectiv C (NSArray)

Comment: Быть может нам не надо задавать ему объект(setObject) а зададим метку (setValue) как думаеш?

Comment: добавьте весь обновленный код на github я посмотрю.

Comment: код обновил. Смотри с этими параметрами setValue,  при записи в консоле пишет что не смог сохранить ( 2016-05-13 23:36:45.692 Swa[7719:631695] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x106984b40> { count = 1, contents =
 "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x106984ef0> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>) а по итогу во всем словаре поменял значение с false на True но без записи в plist ( все 20 позиций стали true даже где не было этих значений он внес их) Вот тебе И Сюрпрайз ))) както по count чтоль нужно...

Comment: По всей видимости это был просто глюк (видать давно не перегружал мас) ошибок больше нету. При перезагрузке симулятора в словарь  не записывается + по нужному индексу менять значение а не во всем словаре.  Вот 2 вопроса.

Comment: Ага вчехлил)) насчет записи)) таки сохраняет в plist )) прошол по пути в свое приложение скомпелированое через симулятор при остановке симулятора значение таки остается, а после как компилирую по новой идет перезапись идет на старый plist который находится в проекте. Вопрос с сохранением походу отпал. Последний вопрос и больше я тебя мучат не буду )) Нужный индекс (indexPath) конкретно по нужному словарю изменение параметра а не по всем словарям, как сообразить ?

Comment: предлагаю уже хадавать новый вопрос :)

Comment: Согласен с тобой )) Вечером задам ))

Comment: [Новый Вопрос)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523615/)