# NsArray и Dictionary или как выбрать конкретный словарь

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Имеем массив со словарями подключенный через plist, также имеем CollectionView который показывает все словаря plist ну и ViewController(VC) по которому мы переходим через CollectionView (по ячейкам в VC). Вопрос состоит в том как выбрать нужный словарь для изменения значение одного из значений словаря по ячейке которой мы перешли.

[image: Plist]

P.s На данном этапе имеем открытие всего массива и изменение всего массива (всех словарей) boolean с false на True с последующим сохранением а необходимо перейдя по конкретной ячейке менять словарь к которой относится конкретная ячейка. Вроде ясно изложил свой вопрос, если не ясно пишите.

[image: DetailViewController]

UPD
Значит перебирает все словари Условие If отрабатывает при нужном индексе, + значение меняется на true (вижу в консоле) остается за малым запись в этот Словарь
[image]

Вот что в Консоле выдает (поставил BreackPoint перед Записью (WriteToFile))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вам надо на основании известных значений в словаре, найти этот самый словарь. Например, найти в массиве словарь у которого значение name == Ant.

```
let results:NSMutableArray = [["name":"Bug"],["name":"Ant"]]

for (index, value) in results.enumerate() {
    let name:String = (value as! NSDictionary)["name"] as! String
    if(name == "Ant") {
        print ("found \(name) at index \(index)")
        var temp = value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        print(temp)
        temp["name"] = "Not Ant"
        results.replaceObjectAtIndex(index, withObject: temp)

    }
}
print(results)
```

Comment: Да можно и так сказать, только не по имени а по index(внутри словаря есть значение) и сравнивать с словарем который подключился в этой ячейке (перейдя с CollectionCell в VC мы имеем все параметры Словаря). Эт я попробую, вопрос как после записать в этот словарь  значение True для correctText и нужно ли будет записывать новые значение после выполнении if  в весь массив Словарей?

Comment: если индекс всегда совпадает - то есть у array[0]  всегда будет index==1, то можно все не проверять, а сразу взять нужный. весь массив записывать не надо. просто заменить нужный на новый.

Comment: Получается у меня ж будет 20 таких проверок (всего 20 ячеек (20 словарей) у каждой ячейки свой словарь). Чем пагубно будет пахнуть если так оставить? . Обновил Вопрос Глянь. Брр, что ты имееш ввиду ?(весь массив записывать не надо. просто заменить нужный на новый. )

Comment: заменить нужный словарь на исправленный.

Comment: как это описать? если не сложно начеркай  мнеб только с этим разобратся и не буду глупых вопросов задовать))

Comment: исправил ответ.